# Text is not showing when I print my HTML page with a background image

Tags: html, css

I am printing an HTML image that has a background url with some formatted text on the it. However, I noticed that when I click on print preview, it only shows the background image without the text that are dynamically placed on it.

```
<div class="certificado_pagina">
        <div class="certificado_conteudo">
            <!-- dynamic content goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

This class selector (certificado_pagina) inherit the background image url.

I have add the css below to the body tag but still not showing the text on the background image

```
@media print {
    body {
        content: url(../images/certificate.png);
        color: #000;
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Most browsers don't print background images to save ink. Oh no! You could find a workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire page ro have background image, you have to specify background image on the `body` element like so:

```
<style>
body {
    background-image: url(...);
}
</style>
```

Comment: This didn’t work and it removed the background image completely leaving only the text

Comment: I have updated my code to match your requirements. Give it a shot.